# Consistency between two Varnish servers behind AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, varnish

We are using ELB to load balance requests between two different Nginx+Varnish servers in two different AZs.  These Varnish servers have been configured to balance requests to another ELB distributing requests to our app servers.  In this way, we should be able to keep the site working if one AZ stops working.

The issue we are facing with this approach is that we don't know how to keep the site from serving different cached objects to the same client, i.e. keeping the consistency of the cached content between the two Varnish servers.

One possible solution would be using ELB's IP hashing so that depending on the client IP one Varnish or the other would serve the request.  This would mitigate the problem somewhat.

Is there any other way to sync the contents between these two Varnish servers?

Comment: Hi there,

I believe you have more knowledge then me on this subject, but you could look into hashing the requested url, wouldn't that be better then hashing the ip? Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

There is no active state synchronization available in Varnish.

You can do this with a helper processes that tails varnishlog and call out to the other n Varnish servers, but this is brittle and will probably break on you. The common approach is just to do round-robin and have enough traffic that everything is cached where it needs to be. :)

There is some underlying knowledge of how your application behaves baked into your question, but not so many details. Why is it a problem that a different backend has made the response? If they are identical (since you want redundancy, I'd expect that they were?) this shouldn't be an issue.

If the backend replies with user-specific response data for some URLs, it should tell Varnish that with the Vary header.

Adding session stickyness (~ip hashing) in ELB will just hide your problem until one of the AZs goes down and traffic is rerouted, at which point I'd guess you are pretty busy already.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ELB stickiness to achieve what you need, there is no varnish cluster which shares state between varnish instances.